# Automate import of .xls file into SQL Server Express database

Tags: sql-server, import, sql-server-express, xls

I need to import a daily report into an SQL Server database.

I get the daily report in **.xls** format, I can manually go into SQL Server Management Studio and import the excel file but it isn't ideal to do this everyday. I am only using SQL Server Express so don't have the option to save the import.

Comment: There are many ways this could be done. This seems like it is too broad unless you can refine this question quite a bit.

Comment: Hi Sean, thank you for the reply. I want to set a daily task to import a xls file into an sql database table.

Comment: Yeah I kind of got that from your question. But there are dozens of ways to accomplish this. I don't work with sql express but I don't think you can use the scaled down SSIS there to import data. That most likely means you will have to write some incredibly ugly sql, or write a CLR procedure, or just do this in a programming language and schedule it with windows scheduler.

Comment: As Sean Lange mentioned there are different ways to import the data. one among them is create an SSIS package and schedule the package  to run at what ever time you need the data.

Comment: Is it possible to create an SSIS package when using SQL Express?

Answer (score 1):

If you can use openrowset with the excel file (as discussed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/import-data-from-excel-to-sql?view=sql-server-2017) - along with other approaches), you could stuff the code into a procedure and then use the windows task scheduler to run sqlcmd which will execute the procedure. More than likely you could also do something similar using excel automation (or a little vba). BCP is an option if you can use the more common CSV (or delimited) format.